# Bootstrap modal not working with codeigniter form_open()

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Bootstrap Modal code

```html
<!-- Signup Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="signUpForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Please Sing Up</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo form_open('Registration')?>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="login-email" class="control-label">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login-email" id="login-email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username" class="control-label">Username:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password" class="control-label">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Signup</button>
      </div>
      <?php echo form_close()?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have controller named Registration. when I click on button to launch the modal nothing happens. Button code that launches the modal.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpForm">Signup
</button>
```

Comment: Please consider adding an example of actual HTML output, it's hard to tell what is wrong from code snippets above.

Comment: Works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/krs26xff/)**.. Are they in separate page? That shouldn't matter but just check for any console errors!

Comment: Yes it works fine with out <?php echo form_open()?>. But after adding this line the modal is not appearing on button click. Yes they are on same page. I tried giving the class to my form by using $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal'); but same result.

Answer (score 0):

You should add jQuery bootstrap "REQUEST"

More info here http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to jquery and bootstrap.min.js files in header and also add links for bootstrap css files.